# Ontologies and Graph-tool Python

Tags: python, ontology, graph-tool

Is there a way to create a graph from an ontology file using [Graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) library in Python?

I've done some research and what I've found is:

- Graph Tool doesn't support .owl and .rdf files.
- There is no obvious way to convert an ontology to a graph using this library, as far as I know (I hope I missed something that someone here knows about).

***What I have tried:***

I had the idea of converting OWL ontologies and OBO to a [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) Graph then to a Graph-tool graph (because all of my previous work was done with Graph-tool).

**Method 1:** Used [onto2nx](https://github.com/cthoyt/onto2nx#onto2nx---) library.

*Problems:*

- Really slow at loading ontologies and it stops half way.
- Isn't documented at all so I couldn't even get an idea on how it works even after checking the source code (The person who created it was notified but didn't reply).

**Method 2:** Used [RDFLib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib#rdflib) library.

I've based my solution no this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54095269/7138725) but:

*Problems:*

- The method to store the networkx ontology graph in a GraphML file doesn't support [the mixed graphs (directed and unidirected edges together)](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.graphml.write_graphml.html#write-graphml) which is exactly what I need.

Comment: While it is not graph-tool you might have a look to this example notebook which depicts bfo.owl with the help of networkx and nxv (graphviz-based): https://github.com/cknoll/semantictools/blob/main/doc/demo_notebooks/bfo_visualization.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

https://readthedocs.org/projects/the-data-driven-ontology-toolkit-ddot/downloads/pdf/latest/

It has a function tonetworkx, maybe that’ll help.

Comment: Will check it out. Thank you.